# Proper way of handling 'null' in 'select' form

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem with handling `null` value in `select` form and returning proper message, that this value can't be `null`.

My view (part of the form):

```
<label>Producer:</label>
<select class="form-control" th:field="*{producer.id}" th:errorclass="has-error">
    <option value="0">Select producer</option>
    <option th:each="producer : ${producers}"
        th:value="${producer?.id}"
        th:text="${producer?.producerName}">
    </option>
</select>
<span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('producer')}">
    <ul>
        <li th:each="err : ${#fields.errors('producer')}" th:text="${'- ' + err}"/>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Part of Malt controller:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="producer_id")
private Producer producer;
```

Spring (or thymeleaf?) requires `value`, so I set it to `0` - This relation is ManyToMany, and values are taken from database - there is no `0`, so error is thrown:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Attribute "value" is required in "option" tags (template: "malt/createOrUpdateMaltForm" - line 55, col 9)
```

I have tried few different approaches, but I am not able to return any error message to the form, informing user to choose one of the available option.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'd say this error you are getting comes up because here: th:value="${producer?.id}", sometimes producer?.id is null. Are you passing that field correctly from your controller?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing it correctly. When I'm adding new malt, or update existing one, and populate `producer` field with proper value - it is ok. When I'm creating, or updating `malt`, and I didn't choose proper value, and stick to this value `Select producer` with id=0, I want to inform user about incorrect value, but I only get error on page